# Round robin algorithm in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a list of directories. (say a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
I need to get the directory last modified and access the next one to put some files over there (say if a3 is the latest dir modified ie, last time files were put into a3, this time I need to move the files in a4)…and if a5 is the last modified dir, I need to move the files in a1. thus it works in a round robin manner. Can u pls suggest how do I achieve this ?

Comment: how do you define "next one"?

Comment: I have not defined the "next one", once we will get the value of last modified folder, we will increment it by one.

Comment: is this some ridiculously complicated way of saying you want the least recently modified directory?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I did not mean to complicate it, what I was looking for, is a solution which is comprehendible. I do not have any idea how to go about it with round robin algorithm, it would be nice if you can site some solution to it.

Comment: so your answer is...?

Answer (score 0):

This will work only on systems that have the stat command.  Your question needs lots more information to give you decent answer - UNIX OS for example.  This is clumsy for that reason.
There better ways to do this.

```
oldestdir=$( stat -c "%n %Y" a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 | sort -k2rn | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
```

$oldestdir is the name of the LRU directory as @KarolyHorvath pointed out.  You cannot "increment this by one"